# Draw doughnut chart with titles in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, charts, draw

Any idea how to draw a doughnut chart with titles like this:

[image]

I tried several libraries, but with no success. I can't create these white lines between each slice. Underlined titles are too difficult for me too. Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **CABasicAnimation** to draw arcs, for example

[none tested code]

```
// e.g. 0.3 is 30%
func calculateEndAngle(percentageAsDouble: Double) -> CGFloat {
  let endAngle:CGFloat = CGFloat(2 * M_PI - (M_PI * percentageAsDouble))
  return endAngle
}

let animationCenter:CGPoint = self.view.center
let animationRadius:CGFloat = 100.0
let animationLineWidth:CGFloat = 16.0
let endAngle = calculateEndAngle(0.3)
let arcPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: animationCenter, radius: animationRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(M_PI), endAngle:endAngle, clockwise: true)

let arcLayer = CAShapeLayer()
arcLayer.path = arcPath.CGPath
arcLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
arcLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
arcLayer.lineWidth = animationLineWidth

self.view.layer.addSublayer(arcLayer)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is good, but how to calculate the angles depending on some data? 
Like, having three values - 30%, 50% and 20%? How to draw these three slices with white lines between them?

Comment: so a full circle is 2 * M_PI, so you need to keep a list of start and end values each of the correct arc length (0.3 * 2 * M_PI is 30% but you will need to offset the angles depending on where the 30% starts).

Comment: Could you please post a piece of code showing this?
Using dummy data - 50%, 30%, 20%. No matter where it starts.

Comment: okay - I added an example calculation, again not tested. To be honest you should now take this example and build on it to get the effect that you want

Comment: I did everything, only problem is these titles. I have no idea how to create this line from the center of the slice.

Comment: yeah they are going to be harder. Well done on getting the arc stuff working though...

Comment: Any idea how to add them? I need a line from the center of the slice. No need to be exactly like in the example.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below library :

[1.danielgindi/ios-charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

[image]